# method for accomplishing both .closest and .prev exist?

Tags: jquery, dom

**Html:**

```
<div class="ancestor">
  <div class="sibling"><input class="findMe" /></div>
  <button>find findMe</button>
</div>
```

**or (input is direct sibling)**

```
<input class="findMe" />
<button>find findMe</button>
```

Is there a way to find the .findMe if the button is clicked?  Basically, something that will check ancestors, previous siblings (second snippet), and children within siblings (first snippet).

**Js:**

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var btn = $(this);
  // what I'm after...
  var input = btn.findSomethingThatExistsAnywhereAboveMe(".findMe") 
});
```

Comment: When you say children within ancestors, I take it you are talking about the immediate parent only as ancestor?

Comment: your first snippet shows siblings, no ancestors.

Comment: I've edited the snippets to reflect the descriptions of said snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with the code you have provided.

How is the script supposed to know you mean that specific `.findMe` element, you could have any number of those elements within the same document.

However, if you have a parent element around this markup, then you could find that specific `.findMe`.

```
<div class="parentElement">
  <div class="ancestor">
    <input class="findMe" />
  </div>
  <button>find findMe</button>
</div>
```

**Or**

```
<div class="parentElement">
  <input class="findMe" />
  <button>find findMe</button>
</div>
```

Then you could do:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var btn = $(this);
  var input = btn.parents(".parentElement").find(".findMe");
});
```